# replacing a piece of string from a dictionary value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns, let's say

```
data = {'features': ['2q07_female', '2q06_male'], 'importance': [0.25, 0.30]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and I want to use a dictionary

```
dictnames = {'2q07': 'color of hair', 's2q06': 'color of eyes'}
```

to help me replace the values in order to have a dataframe

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'features': ['color of hair_female', 'color of eyes_male'], 
                       'importance': [0.25, 0.30]})
```

Could someone tell me a simple way to do this?

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592)

Comment: chk 's2q06' in `dictnames`. is it current? not '2q06'?

Answer (score 2):

Given

```
data = {'features': ['2q07_female', '2q06_male'], 'importance': [0.25, 0.30]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
dictnames = {'2q07': 'color of hair', '2q06': 'color of eyes'} # fixed key s2q06
```

do

```
import re
pat = re.compile('|'.join(f'({re.escape(k)})' for k in dictnames))
df['features'] = df['features'].str.replace(pat, lambda m:dictnames.get(m.group(0)))
```

which updates `df` to

```
               features  importance
0  color of hair_female        0.25
1    color of eyes_male        0.30
```

You could also do

```
for k, v in dictnames.items():
    df['features'] = df['features'].str.replace(k, v)
```

but it would be very slow for larger dictionaries. [Panda Kim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20430449/panda-kim)'s  answer should be the fastest as long as your data is structured like `"KeyToReplace_rest of string"`.

Comment: I'd go for `pat = re.compile(f"({'|'.join(map(re.escape, dictnames))})")` ;)

Comment: hi, this `for k, v in dictnames.items():
    df['features'] = df['features'].str.replace(k, v)` does not replace string which include '(' or ')' unfortunately. Any solution to this?

Comment: @VickyVoukè: I believe it's treating those as regular expression characters.  Try replacing `str.replace(k, v)` with `str.replace(re.escape(k), v)`. Or use my first solution.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski this does not work :( . And I wish it did, because it is easier to debug in the future. The first solution works yes.

Answer (score 1):

I thought 's2q06' in dictnames as '2q06' and solved problem.

**Example**

```
data = {'features': ['2q07_female', '2q06_male'], 'importance': [0.25, 0.30]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
dictnames = {'2q07': 'color of hair', '2q06': 'color of eyes'}
```

**Code**

```
s = df['features'].str.split('_')
```

`s`

```
0    [2q07, female]
1      [2q06, male]
```

edit `feature` column

```
df.assign(features=s.str[0].replace(dictnames).str.cat(s.str[1], sep='_'))
```

output:

```
    features                importance
0   color of hair_female    0.25
1   color of eyes_male      0.30
```

When there is key in feature column that does not correspond to `dictnames`, the handling is not clear, so i use `replace`.

Comment: This will perform very well as long as the data starts with the string to be replaced followed by an underscore.